# How to make the console print something by pressing a key like F2 or F3

Tags: c++, windows, input, switch-statement

UPDATE! I figured out how to find the keys and defined them in my code. The problem is I don't know how to make it so the console prints the selection and it gives u time to press a key. Then it gets plugged into to the switch which prints the current gun depending on the key pressed. I am also using windows 10. I also have encountered another problem I want it to print out Guns first then ask for an input (this part works fine) but then instead of just printing the attachments, it prints out both attachments and the humanized level.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

#define KEY_F1 17
#define KEY_F2 18
#define KEY_F3 19
#define KEY_F4 20
#define KEY_F5 21
#define KEY_F6 22
#define KEY_F7 23
#define KEY_F8 24
#define KEY_F9 25
#define KEY_F10 26
#define KEY_F11 27
#define KEY_F12 28

#define KEY_N7 103
#define KEY_N8 104
#define KEY_N9 105


int main() {

    char gun;
    char att;
    char hum;

    char key = _getch();
    int value = key;

    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "Developed by ! CaptaiN#9999" << endl;

    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "Guns" << endl;

    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "[F1]   AK" << endl;
    cout << "[F2]   MP5" << endl;
    cout << "[F3]   M2" << endl;
    cout << "[F4]   SAR" << endl;
    cout << "[F5]   Tommy" << endl;
    cout << "[F6]   Custom" << endl;
    cin >> gun;


    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "Attachnments" << endl;

    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "[F7]   Holosight" << endl;
    cout << "[F8]   Simplesight" << endl;
    cout << "[F9]   Silencer" << endl;
    cout << "[F10]  8x Zoom Scope" << endl;
    cout << "[F11]  16x Zoom Scope" << endl;
    cout << "[F12]  No Attachment" << endl;
    cin >> att;

    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "Humanize Levels" << endl;

    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "[Numpad 7]  3 (HIGH)" << endl;
    cout << "[Numpad 8]  2 (MODERATE)" << endl;
    cout << "[Numpad 9]  1 (LOW)" << endl;
    cin >> hum;




    //system("CLS");

    while (value != KEY_X) {

        switch (_getch()) {

        case KEY_F1:
            cout << "Current Gun: AK" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_F2:
            cout << "Current Gun: MP5" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_F3:
            cout << "Current Gun: M2" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_F4:
            cout << "Current Gun: SAR" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_F5:
            cout << "Current Gun: Tommy" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_F6:
            cout << "Current Gun: Custom" << endl;
            break;
        }

        switch (att) {

        case KEY_F7:
            cout << "Current Attachment: Holosight" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_F8:
            cout << "Current Attachment: Simplesight" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_F9:
            cout << "Current Attachment: Silencer" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_F10:
            cout << "Current Attachment: 8x Zoom Scope" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_F11:
            cout << "Current Attachment: 16x Zoom Scope" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_F12:
            cout << "Current Attachment: None" << endl;
            break;
        }

        switch (hum) {

        case KEY_N7:
            cout << "Humanized Level: 3" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_N8:
            cout << "Humanized Level: 2" << endl;
            break;
        case KEY_N9:
            cout << "Humanized Level: 1" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us some code,

Comment: There isn't even a standard way to make your program print anything if you press a common key like `A` (without pressing return afterwards). You'll need platform specific code for such things. There are libraries that works on most platforms, like `ncurses` and `pdcurses`.

Answer (score 2):

I think [pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173397/pm100)'s answer is a perfectly acceptable way to do this, but the resulting code from such a technique would be fragile and dependent on the platform (because there's no standard representation as he mentions).

If that's fine with you, use his answer. A more portable way to do this would be to use a terminal control library, the most common one being curses 
(it's technically a c library FYI). There are two main implementations: [pdcurses](https://pdcurses.org/) mainly for Windows and [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) for Mac and Linux. I won't go over set up here since that will mostly depend on the library, but if you want to make it cross-platform you can use [cmake](https://cmake.org/) but that isn't super easy (because you have to handle pdcurses and ncurses separately).

Regardless of curses implementation, a minimal example of capturing the F1-F12 keys is below:

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <pdcurses.h>
#else
#include <ncurses.h>
#endif

int main()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    while (true) {
        int ch = getch();
        if (ch >= KEY_F(1) && ch <= KEY_F(12)) {
            printw("F* key pressed\n");
        }
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

for additional details on the library I recommend [this](http://www.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~hughm/os/notes/ncurses.html#using) programming guide.

as a side note, you might want to consider something like [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to map your keys to std::string as it would be a little less verbose than using switch statements.

Comment: All the way with you except for "something like std::unordered_multimap", this container seems like a poor choice here. I'd use a simple map<int, String>.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, the multi aspect of the map is totally unneeded, and the performance gain from it being unordered would be negligible. I'll edit my answer to reflect that. Thanks for catching me!

Answer (score 1):

there is not standard representation of function keys. So start out by working out what chars arrive at your app when Fn is pressed. Quite likely that its more than one char.

on linux you can do

```
cat > fn.bin
od -tx2 fn.bin
```

this shows what chars are generated by Fn

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so since your question has basically changed, I'll put a new answer to address it. I see you've gone with the platform-specific option. Luckily, I'm on Windows 10 as well, so I can still help.

First things first, I'm having some difficulty with the keycodes you listed in your defines - I'm getting a null character (0) and then some other character like ; (59) for F1 and > (60) for F2. For F11 and F12 I get a completely different set of characters (as you can see in my code). I'm not really sure why we'd be getting different results, maybe something weird with encodings? Would you mind stating where you found the character codes listed in the snippet? For the rest of my answer, I'll just use what I'm getting (sorry, I don't know what else to do).

Here is the code that will achieve what I think you want - it gets the user's initial "loadout" in the first part of the code. In the main loop it allows you to enter a new weapon, and just prints the attachment selected earlier. I didn't add handling for the number pad keys, but the technique should be the same if you want to do it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <array>
#include <map>

// define the parts for all F* keys
using multipart_t = std::array<int, 2>;
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F1 = { 0, 59 };
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F2{ 0, 60 };
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F3{ 0, 61 };
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F4{ 0, 62 };
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F5{ 0, 63 };
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F6{ 0, 64 };
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F7{ 0, 65 };
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F8{ 0, 66 };
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F9{ 0, 67 };
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F10{ 0, 68 };
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F11 = { 224, 133 };
constexpr multipart_t KEY_F12 = { 224, 134 };

// map those arrays to the corresponding ints
const std::map<multipart_t, int> F_KEY_TO_INT{
    { KEY_F1, 1 },
    { KEY_F2, 2 },
    { KEY_F3, 3 },
    { KEY_F4, 4 },
    { KEY_F5, 5 },
    { KEY_F6, 6 },
    { KEY_F7, 7 },
    { KEY_F8, 8 },
    { KEY_F9, 9 },
    { KEY_F10, 10 },
    { KEY_F11, 11 },
    { KEY_F12, 12 }
};

// add a utility function that returns the pressed key as an int of 1-12 (for F1-F12 keys)
int fGetch() {
    // TODO: add checking to check it actually is an F* key instead of just failing silently (REALLY BAD)
    multipart_t keys;
    keys[0] = _getch();
    keys[1] = _getch();
    return F_KEY_TO_INT.find(keys)->second;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "" << '\n';

    std::cout << "Developed by ! CaptaiN#9999" << '\n';

    std::cout << "" << '\n';

    std::cout << "Guns" << '\n';

    std::cout << "" << '\n';

    std::cout << "[F1]   AK" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[F2]   MP5" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[F3]   M2" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[F4]   SAR" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[F5]   Tommy" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[F6]   Custom" << '\n';
    // TODO: valid character checking (for all 3)
    int gun(fGetch());


    std::cout << "" << '\n';

    std::cout << "Attachnments" << '\n';

    std::cout << "" << '\n';

    std::cout << "[F7]   Holosight" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[F8]   Simplesight" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[F9]   Silencer" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[F10]  8x Zoom Scope" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[F11]  16x Zoom Scope" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[F12]  No Attachment" << '\n';
    int att(fGetch());

    // I'll leave you to handle function keys, it should be basically the same
    /*std::cout << "" << '\n';

    std::cout << "Humanize Levels" << '\n';

    std::cout << "" << '\n';

    std::cout << "[Numpad 7]  3 (HIGH)" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[Numpad 8]  2 (MODERATE)" << '\n';
    std::cout << "[Numpad 9]  1 (LOW)" << '\n';
    std::cin >> hum;*/

    system("CLS");

    std::cout << "main loop start" << '\n';
    int value = 0;
    while (value != 'x') {
        value = fGetch();

        switch (value) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Current Gun: AK" << '\n';
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Current Gun: MP5" << '\n';
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "Current Gun: M2" << '\n';
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "Current Gun: SAR" << '\n';
            break;
        case 5:
            std::cout << "Current Gun: Tommy" << '\n';
            break;
        case 6:
            std::cout << "Current Gun: Custom" << '\n';
            break;
        }

        switch (att) {

        case 7:
            std::cout << "Current Attachment: Holosight" << '\n';
            break;
        case 8:
            std::cout << "Current Attachment: Simplesight" << '\n';
            break;
        case 9:
            std::cout << "Current Attachment: Silencer" << '\n';
            break;
        case 10:
            std::cout << "Current Attachment: 8x Zoom Scope" << '\n';
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Current Attachment: 16x Zoom Scope" << '\n';
            break;
        case 12:
            std::cout << "Current Attachment: None" << '\n';
            break;
        }

        // TODO
        /*switch (hum) {

        case KEY_N7:
            std::cout << "Humanized Level: 3" << '\n';
            break;
        case KEY_N8:
            std::cout << "Humanized Level: 2" << '\n';
            break;
        case KEY_N9:
            std::cout << "Humanized Level: 1" << '\n';
            break;
        }*/
    }
}
```

In the code, I've added places for you to improve upon mine (it's mostly checking for a user typing the wrong key at the wrong time).

The actual input was handled by putting the multiple characters into an array and using a map to map that to the appropriate int for that F1-F12 key. Please note that the function currently has next to no error checking.